# Multiprocess inherently shared memory in no longer working on python 3.10 (coming from 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I understand there are a variety of techniques for sharing memory and data structures between processes in python. This question is specifically about this inherently shared memory in python scripts that existed in python 3.6 but seems to no longer exist in 3.10.  **Does anyone know why and if it's possible to bring this back in 3.10?  Or what this change that I'm observing is?**  I've upgraded my Mac to Monterey and it no longer supports python 3.6, so I'm forced to upgrade to either 3.9 or 3.10+.

Note:  I tend to develop on Mac and run production on Ubuntu.  Not sure if that factors in here.  Historically with 3.6, everything behaved the same regardless of OS.

Make a simple project with the following python files

**myLibrary.py**

```
MyDict = {}
```

**test.py**

```
import threading
import time
import multiprocessing

import myLibrary


def InitMyDict():
    myLibrary.MyDict = {'woot': 1, 'sauce': 2}
    print('initialized myLibrary.MyDict to ', myLibrary.MyDict)


def MainLoop():
    numOfSubProcessesToStart = 3
    for i in range(numOfSubProcessesToStart):
        t = threading.Thread(
            target=CoolFeature(),
            args=())
        t.start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)


def CoolFeature():
    MyProcess = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=SubProcessFunction,
        args=())
    MyProcess.start()


def SubProcessFunction():
    print('SubProcessFunction: ', myLibrary.MyDict)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    InitMyDict()
    MainLoop()
```

When I run this on 3.6 it has a significantly different behavior than 3.10.  I do understand that a subprocess cannot modify the memory of the main process, but it is still super convenient to access the main process' data structure that was previously set up as opposed to moving every little tiny thing into shared memory just to read a simple dictionary/int/string/etc.

**Python 3.10 output:**

```
python3.10 test.py 
initialized myLibrary.MyDict to  {'woot': 1, 'sauce': 2}
SubProcessFunction:  {}
SubProcessFunction:  {}
SubProcessFunction:  {}
```

**Python 3.6 output:**

```
python3.6 test.py 
initialized myLibrary.MyDict to  {'woot': 1, 'sauce': 2}
SubProcessFunction:  {'woot': 1, 'sauce': 2}
SubProcessFunction:  {'woot': 1, 'sauce': 2}
SubProcessFunction:  {'woot': 1, 'sauce': 2}
```

Observation:

Notice that in 3.6, the subprocess can view the value that was set from the main process.  But in 3.10, the subprocess sees an empty dictionary.

Comment: `target=CoolFeature()` does not make sense. Why does this test case need threads in the first palce?

Comment: @o11c You can ignore the thread.  This behavior still exists without threads.  The test case does not need threads at all.  I was trying to reproduce the bug, and was trying to closely resemble what my code was doing.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with `multiprocessing`, but is it possible you're using a `spawn` based pool rather than a `fork` based pool?

Comment: This is not "inherently shared memory". `multiprocessing` has never offered such a feature. Are you on Mac? The default start method changed in 3.8 on Mac, which would explain the observed difference.

Comment: @o11c This may be spot on.  See link below. 
 "Changed in version 3.8: On macOS, the spawn start method is now the default. The fork start method should be considered unsafe as it can lead to crashes of the subprocess".  But I wonder what this means for Ubuntu vs mac here... Since I use both. 
 https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Read the link I commented above, about the fork method:  "All resources of the parent are inherited by the child process".  Intersting.  I wasn't aware there were so many unique ways to start a process

Comment: @LampShade does `forkserver` work? Remember that it is *dangerous* to call `fork` in a multithreaded process (unless you can carefully write async-signal-safe code and then immediately call `exec`, which is IMPOSSIBLE in Python and also incompatible with what you are doing anyway). But if you can do the `fork` *before* creating any threads it should work fine.

Comment: "resource of the parent are inherited".  That does not mean "shared".  A forked process gets a copy (more likely copy on write).  If a process changes its copy the other processes don't see the change.

Comment: @o11c My main process is multi-threaded.  So it sounds like this could cause issues.  Those issues only occur on a mac right?  My production servers are all Ubuntu.  But what do you mean exactly by   "if you can do the fork before creating any threads it should work fine".  Do you mean if I call `multiprocessing.set_start_method("fork")` before starting any threads?  Or do you mean if I spawn my sub processes before starting any threads?  As of right now, I am starting threads on the main process before starting the sub processes.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yep, exactly right.  That's super useful in many cases.

Comment: @LampShade It's a problem on all fork-based systems: there may be locks that aren't reset on fork. On Linux, GLIBC *tries* to reset locks if it knows about them, but locks in other libraries are hopeless. ... I mean `set_start_method("forkserver")`. Since I'm not familiar with `multiprocessing`, you *might* have to call (or you could just call a dummy task maybe); note that this will only work if your data is calculated before the fork (and before threads) ... Also: `set_start_method("fork")` will NOT work on MacOS since the reason the default changed was because it started crashing reliably.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, since 3.8, CPython uses the *spawn* start method on MacOs. Before it used the *fork* method.

On UNIX platforms, the *fork* start method is used which means that every new `multiprocessing` process is an exact copy of the parent at the time of the fork.

The *spawn* method means that it starts a new Python interpreter for each new `multiprocessing` process. According to the documentation:

> The child process will only inherit those resources necessary to run the process object’s `run()` method.

It will *import* your program into this new interpreter, so starting processes et cetera sould only be done from within the `if __name__ == '__main__':`-block!

This means you cannot count on variables from the parent process being available in the children, *unless they are module level constants which would be imported*.

So the change is significant.

**What can be done?**

If the required information *could* be a module-level constant, that would solve the problem in the simplest way.

If that is not possible (e.g. because the data needs to be generated at runtime) you could have the parent write the information to be shared to a file. E.g. in JSON format and before it starts other processes. Then the children could simply read this. That is probably the next simplest solution.

Using a `multiprocessing.Manager` would allow you to share a `dict` between processes. There is however a certain amount of overhead associated with this.

Or you could try calling `multiprocessing.set_start_method("fork")` before creating processes or pools and see if it doesn't crash in your case. That would revert to the pre-3.8 method on MacOs. But as documented [in this bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue33725), there are real problems with using the `fork` method on MacOs.
Reading the issue indicates that `fork` **might** be OK *as long as you don't use threads*.

Comment: Thank you this post helped sort out a very tricky bug we had. 

As an aside having different behaviour on different platforms breaks the principle of least surprise. This should be called out more clearly in documentation.

Comment: @UsmanIsmail  The different behavior is not something that the Python developers can help.   It's kind of amazing that they got multiprocessing to work as well as it does without `fork`.  And start methods *are* mentioned in the manual. Although I agree that it could be more prominent.